# Encrypting and Decrypting in change password function?

Tags: c#, mysql, encryption, aes

I would like to execute a change password function, The following shows the code and screenshots of what I have done so far:

```
        private void Password_Change()
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        string query = "UPDATE staff_user SET staff_password = @newpassword WHERE staff_password = @staff_password";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbyouthworkConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        ConfirmPassword.Text = Encrypt(ConfirmPassword.Text.Trim());
        CurrentPassword.Text = Decrypt(CurrentPassword.Text.Trim());
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
                    con.Open();


                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())


                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staff_password",CurrentPassword.Text );
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpassword", (ConfirmPassword.Text));
                    cmd.Connection = con;


                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();

                }


                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    Label1.Text = "Password has been changed successfully.";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label1.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
                }
                if (CurrentPassword.Text == New_Password.Text)
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label1.Text = "Old Password and New Password cannot be the same !";
                }

                if (CurrentPassword.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text)
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label1.Text = "Old Password and New Password cannot be the same !";
                }

            }
        }
    }
    private string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

However when I run the project
This is the error i get:
[image]

I can't seem to see where I have gone since i have used the same decrypt function for when the user logs in and the encrypt function when the user creates an account.

Comment: Since passwords are never stored (encrypted or plain text) your code looks strange. Please verify that actual code hashes passwords and does not encrypt them and code in the post  is just sample of some random field encrypted/decrypted.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What makes you think "passwords are never stored (encrypted or plain text)", sure they shouldn't be but in reality they are all to often are.

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: "The input data is not a complete block."

AES is a block cypher, it works with data block by block and the blocs have a size of 16-bytes. If the data is not a multiple of the block size it must be padded in some way, the usual padding used for AES is [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) née PKCS#5.

Add that padding option to the encryption code. The padding will be added on encryption and deleted on decryption. You will need to ensure the encryption output buffer is one block (16-bytes) longer than the input data.